# Create A New iOS Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrol

I am trying to create a new control for Xcode to implement into a new iOS app. The end idea is to display the formation of a football squad graphically. I realise that this could all be coded programmatically but I want to create a new control to represent a player and then load the formation accordingly as I may add other player information to the control in the future.

I have created a xib view file, in which is a label for displaying their name. I have tried the following but the label's text doesn't show up. Am I missing something obvious?

[I have included the correct headers and have connected the label up and set the xib to the new class]

header file for xib:

```
@interface playerObject : UIControl
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *playerNameLabel;
@end
```

implementation file for xib:

```
#import "playerObject.h"
@interface playerObject ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@end

@implementation playerObject
- (void) setPlayerNameLabel:(NSString *)playerNameLabel
{
    self.nameLabel.text = playerNameLabel;
}
```

View Controller Implementation File:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    playerObject *newPlayer = [[playerObject alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 150)];

    [newPlayer setPlayerNameLabel:@"TEST"];
    [newPlayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:newPlayer];

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may have created a xib file containing a label however you do not appear to be using it. You are creating a new instance of the `playerObject` class instead of loading one from a xib file. Take a look at the `UINib` class documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your custom view without loading it from the .xib file.
In order to make it work, follow these steps:

1. Make your `playerObject` inherit from `UIView` instead of `UIControl`.
2. Open your `.xib` file.
3. Select the root view on the left pane.
4. On the right pane, switch to the Identity Inspector tab.
5. Type `playerObject` into the first text field "Class".
6. Make sure that you connected all your `IBOutlets` within Interface Builder.
7. Do the following to load your custom `UIView` from the `.xib` file:

   ```
   playerObject *newPlayer = (playerObject *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibFilename" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
   newPlayer.playerNameLabel = @"Lionel Messi";
   ```

Note aside: I strongly recommend you to start using "namespaces" for your classes (it's just a two-letter prefix), such as `XXPlayerObject`, with XX being something else you consider describes your app / module. All other related custom classes should "share" this namespace. Look at what Apple does with its classes.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: FYI the ping above does not work to ping the user as they have not participated on this post yet.